# Email Activity - White space is being removed

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We have an email activity that is getting created via a plugin. The email will become an SMS and as part of this we are padding the Description to 160 characters.

This functionality used to work however has stopped working in the last few months. I believe this is because Dynamics CRM now uses the "white-space: normal;" attribute.

This means the following code does not work as the white space padding is reduced to a single space. Has anyone got a workable fix for this?

```
string message = "My Message";
if (message.Length < 160)
{
message= message.PadRight(160, ' ');
message+= ".";
}

Email email = new Email();
email.Description = message;
email.To = toEmail;
email.From = fromEmail;
var emailId = service.Create(email);
```

Comment: Why not just leave the message less that 160 characters?

Comment: When it is pushed out as an email the email footer gets added "Protected by blah blah . . ." which we have been told to remove

Answer (score 0):

We were having problems with signatures getting added to E-mails going out and having signatures added.  My understand is that a new user was created and when creating SMS emails we assign them to that user queue.  Since the e-mail entity is still associated with the activity party of the creating user it still shows up in the correct records but is actually gets sent out by the other queue.